# Multiple ViewControllers onscreen

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I would like to place two UIViewControllers on a window (like you can see below). Is it possible to set this up to each view is controlled by it's own controller respectively?
[image]

In the app delegate I'm adding the subview the following way

```
TabBarViewController *tabBarVC = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
CGRect frame = tabBarVC.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = self.window.bounds.size.height - frame.size.height;
tabBarVC.view.frame = frame;
[self.window insertSubview:tabBarVC.view aboveSubview:tabVC.view];
```

It loads, but when I click on a button (IBAction), or do anything which needs the controller, the app crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: "the app crashes" Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a strong reference for an iVar or property for tabBarVC and change this line:

```
TabBarViewController *tabBarVC = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
```

To:

```
tabBarVC = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
```

Or

```
self.tabBarVC = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can..! have the controllers you want to display as iVars of the view controller you want to display in. Then just use,

```
[MainController addSubview:desiredConroller1.view];
[MainController addSubview:desiredConroller2.view];
```

You can load the controller from the storyboard using,

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_name" bundle:nil];
   desiredController1 =  [membershipStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

you can also use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`